# How to add a body in a get API request just like its possible on Postman

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, next.js

I'm supposed to fetch course materials through this endpoint  using GET`http://localhost:8000/student/material` but it has a body of `{ "batch":"DRB2401" }`  and it works on Postman, the endpoint wont work on its own, it strictly requires the body part so how can an API fetch request be made to populate my next.js page if the endpoint wont work on its own because GET requests don't accept a body and I'm confused on how to deal with this, here is the code I want to integrate the proper request to but it doesn't work.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Card, CardContent, Typography, Grid, ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material';
import RootLayout from '@/layouts/RootLayout';

const MaterialPage = () => {
    const [materials, setMaterials] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchMaterials();
    }, []);

    const fetchMaterials = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/student/material', {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ batch: 'DRB2401' }) // Body needed for the endpoint
            });
            if (response.ok) {
                const data = await response.json();
                setMaterials(data);
            } else {
                throw new Error('Failed to fetch materials');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching materials:', error);
        }
    };

    // Create a custom theme with the desired typography
    const theme = createTheme({
        typography: {
            fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif'
        }
    });

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <RootLayout>
                <Grid container spacing={2}>
                    {materials.map(material => (
                        <Grid item xs={12} key={material._id}>
                            <Card sx={{ backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0', padding: 2 }}>
                                <CardContent>
                                    <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
                                        {material.message}
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Typography variant="body1">
                                        Sender: {material.sender}
                                    </Typography>
                                    {material.file && (
                                        <Typography variant="body1">
                                            File: {material.file}
                                        </Typography>
                                    )}
                                </CardContent>
                            </Card>
                        </Grid>
                    ))}
                </Grid>
            </RootLayout>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
};

export default MaterialPage;
```

and using params wont work since the backend is not configured to do so.

Comment: either use queryParams in the url or add `/:id` after the path, read this to know more about _GET with body_ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: Are you sure Postman makes GET request with body? You know you can generate JS code in Postman and check what it's doing for yourself?